# Is migrate Objc Project which is in AppStore to Swift Project feasible?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, xcode-project

I have a project creat by ObjC, and upload to AppStore.
Recently I got a requirement my boss want to Migrate ObjC project to Swift, and creat a new project language choose Swift.

[image]

I want to know if I use new `Swift` project archive upload to AppStore.
Will users download the same App in AppStore?
Or Apple will be treated as another App?
Because my boss want to keep rating and comments.
Is this idea feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the existing bundle identifier of the objective c app for the new swift app, it will be considered as the same app. Changing the language will not make it a different app in the App Store. Uploading the swift app with a different version number will appear as an update for the users.

You can read more about the upload process [here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev442d7f2ca).